# What should be content of grub2 custom entry to boot to another OS on LVM over LUKS along with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lvm, luks

I have Archlinux installed along with Ubuntu on LVM over LUKS. The problem is I cannot boot to arch from menuentry provided by os-prober. Can anyone tell me the custom entry configuration to dual boot ?

Here is my harddrive partitions:

```
    /boot /dev/sda1 100MB [Ubuntu's Boot Partition]
   /dev/sda5 encypted partition with the following logical volumes:
    General-Home [Home partition of both]
    Ubuntu-Root [Ubuntu / partition]
    General-Swap [Swap Partition]
    Arch-Root [Arch / partion which contains /boot as well]
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is the solution I found with help from arch forum:

Mount `/dev/sda1` as `/boot` and enter the drive entry into `fstab`.

Now os-prober will show both ubuntu and arch.

The only problem with this setup is every time you update grub you need to change `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` as it  sees arch's linux image as main ubuntu's latest linux image and sends ubuntu in previous versions.